# ¿Cómo convertir un string en onjeto con Unity Json Utility?

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, unity, unity2d

Necesito convertir la respuesta de una peticion HTTP de string a json, haciendo uso de Json Utility. Al utilizar `JsonUtility.FromJson<OnjectClass>(jsonString)` y luego tratar de acceder a las propiedades obtengo como respuesta Null.

**La petición HTTP funciona correctamente**, el problema es convertir esa respuesta que esta como string a un objeto para utilizarlo en Unity.

El script es el siguiente.

Respuesta de la peticion ([www.downloadHandler.text](http://www.downloadHandler.text)):

```
{"jwt":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYxY2U3M2MzNTJkOTEwMDAxNjM5NmFlZSIsImlhdCI6MTY0MDkyMDAwMywiZXhwIjoxNjQzNTEyMDAzfQ.3Nl03HAGUmNG4qj_iIogKpeg4XphgYau9sn1kbLy7AE","user":{"confirmed":true,"blocked":false,"_id":"61ce73c352d9100016396aee","username":"Test User","email":"testuser@test.com","phone_number":"3332221111","provider":"local","createdAt":"2021-12-31T03:06:43.958Z","updatedAt":"2021-12-31T03:06:43.975Z","__v":0,"role":{"_id":"61ccdbfe5437c83cc0a11f0d","name":"Authenticated","description":"Default role given to authenticated user.","type":"authenticated","__v":0,"id":"61ccdbfe5437c83cc0a11f0d"},"id":"61ce73c352d9100016396aee"}}
```

Modelo del Json:

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Role
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public bool confirmed { get; set; }
    public bool blocked { get; set; }
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone_number { get; set; }
    public string provider { get; set; }
    public string createdAt { get; set; }
    public string updatedAt { get; set; }
    public int __v { get; set; }
    public Role role { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class RegisterResponseRoot
{
    public string jwt { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}
```

Petición HTTP:

```
    IEnumerator PostData(string uri, WWWForm data)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(uri, data))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                RegisterResponseRoot response = JsonUtility.FromJson<RegisterResponseRoot>(www.downloadHandler.text);
                Debug.Log($"{www.downloadHandler.text}");
                Debug.Log(response.jwt); // aquí deberia incluir el token, pero imprime Null
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es simple. En el modelo del json no se debe usar propiedades. Así:

```
[Serializable]
public class Role
{
    public string _id;
    public string name;
    public string description;
    public string type;
    public int __v;
    public string id;
}
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public bool confirmed;
    public bool blocked;
    public string _id;
    public string username;
    public string email;
    public string phone_number;
    public string provider;
    public string createdAt;
    public string updatedAt;
    public int __v;
    public Role role;
    public string id;
}
[Serializable]
public class RegisterResponseRoot
{
    public string jwt;
    public User user;
}
```